# Why Android Studio 4.1 Not Showing Any Error

Tags: android-studio

I just updated the android studio to 4.1 and no error is showing. Anyone have faced this? I am using windows 10. Power mode is disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings....
I think it solved my problem